# How can I find a specific key from a python dict and then get a value from that key in Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, spotify

I have a python dictionary that looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 1621559698154,
        "user": {
            "uri": "spotify:user:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "name": "Panda",
            "imageUrl": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67757000003b82b54c68ed19f1047912529ef4"
        },
        "track": {
            "uri": "spotify:track:6SJSOont5dooK2IXQoolNQ",
            "name": "Dirty",
            "imageUrl": "http://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273a36e3d46e406deebdd5eafb0",
            "album": {
                "uri": "spotify:album:0NMpswZbEcswI3OIe6ml3Y",
                "name": "Dirty (Live)"
            },
            "artist": {
                "uri": "spotify:artist:4ZgQDCtRqZlhLswVS6MHN4",
                "name": "grandson"
            },
            "context": {
                "uri": "spotify:artist:4ZgQDCtRqZlhLswVS6MHN4",
                "name": "grandson",
                "index": 0
            }
        }
    },
   
    {
        "timestamp": 1621816159299,
        "user": {
            "uri": "spotify:user:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "name": "maja",
            "imageUrl": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67757000003b8286459151d5426f5a9e77cfee"
        },
        "track": {
            "uri": "spotify:track:172rW45GEnGoJUuWfm1drt",
            "name": "Your Best American Girl",
            "imageUrl": "http://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27351630f0f26aff5bbf9e10835",
            "album": {
                "uri": "spotify:album:16i5KnBjWgUtwOO7sVMnJB",
                "name": "Puberty 2"
            },
            "artist": {
                "uri": "spotify:artist:2uYWxilOVlUdk4oV9DvwqK",
                "name": "Mitski"
            },
            "context": {
                "uri": "spotify:playlist:0tol7yRYYfiPJ17BuJQKu2",
                "name": "I Bet on Losing Dogs",
                "index": 0
            }
        }
    }
]
```

How can I get, for example, the group of values for user.name "Panda" and then get that specific "track" list? I can't parse through the list by index because the list order changes randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only looking for "Panda", then you can just loop over the list, check whether the name is "Panda", and then retrieve the track list accordingly.

Otherwise, that would be inefficient if you want to do that for many different users. I would first make a dict that maps user to its index in the list, and then use that for each user (I am assuming that the list does not get modified *while* you execute the code, although it can be modified between executions.)

```py
user_to_id = {data[i]['user']['name']: i for i in range(len(data))} # {'Panda': 0, 'maja': 1}

def get_track(user):
    return data[user_to_id[user]]['track']

print(get_track('maja'))
print(get_track('Panda'))
```

where `data` is the list you provided.

Or, perhaps just make a dictionary of tracks directly:

```py
tracks = {item['user']['name']: item['track'] for item in data}

print(tracks['Panda'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get list of tracks for user `Panda`:

```
tracks = [entry['track'] for entry in data if entry['user']['name'] == 'Panda']
```